# Same function in SELECT and WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Beginner question:

I have an expensive function `f(x, y)` on two columns x and y in my database table.

I want to execute a query that gives me the result of the function as a column and puts a constraint on it, something like

```
SELECT *, f(x, y) AS func FROM table_name WHERE func < 10;
```

However this doesn't work, so I will have to write something like

```
SELECT *, f(x, y) AS func FROM table_name WHERE f(x, y) < 10;
```

Will this run the expensive function twice? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the function `STABLE`/`IMMUTABLE` or `VOLATILE`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's create a function that has a side effect so that we can see how many times it is executed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.this_here(val integer)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RAISE WARNING 'I am called with %', val;
    RETURN sqrt(val);
END;
$function$;
```

And then call this like you do:

```
SELECT this_here(i) FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(i) WHERE this_here(i) < 2;

WARNING:  I am called with 1
WARNING:  I am called with 1
WARNING:  I am called with 2
WARNING:  I am called with 2
WARNING:  I am called with 3
WARNING:  I am called with 3
WARNING:  I am called with 4
WARNING:  I am called with 5
WARNING:  I am called with 6
WARNING:  I am called with 7
WARNING:  I am called with 8
WARNING:  I am called with 9
WARNING:  I am called with 10
    this_here     
──────────────────
                1
  1.4142135623731
 1.73205080756888
(3 rows)
```

As you see, the function is called at least once (from the `WHERE` clause), and when the condition is true, once again to produce the output.

To avoid the second execution, you can do what [Edgar suggests](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196222/6219) - namely wrap the query and filter the result set:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT this_here(i) AS val FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(i)) x 
 WHERE x.val < 2;

WARNING:  I am called with 1
... every value only once ...
WARNING:  I am called with 10
```

To further check how this works, one can go to [`pg_stat_user_functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-USER-FUNCTIONS-VIEW) and check `calls` there (given [`track_functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-FUNCTIONS) is set to 'all).

Let's try with something that has no side effect:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.simple(val numeric)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT sqrt(val);
$function$;

SELECT simple(i) AS v 
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(i)
 WHERE simple(i) < 2;
-- output omitted

SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_functions WHERE funcname = 'simple';
-- 0 rows
```

`simple()` is actually too simple so it can be [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions), therefore it does not appear in the view.  Let's make it un-inlinable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.other_one(val numeric)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT 1; -- to prevent inlining
SELECT sqrt(val);
$function$;

SELECT other_one(i) AS v
  FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(i)
 WHERE other_one(i) < 2;

SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_functions ;
 funcid │ schemaname │ funcname  │ calls │ total_time │ self_time 
────────┼────────────┼───────────┼───────┼────────────┼───────────
 124311 │ test       │ other_one │    13 │      0.218 │     0.218

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT other_one(i) AS v FROM generate_series(1,10) AS t(i)) x 
 WHERE v < 2;

SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_functions ;
 funcid │ schemaname │ funcname  │ calls │ total_time │ self_time 
────────┼────────────┼───────────┼───────┼────────────┼───────────
 124311 │ test       │ other_one │    23 │      0.293 │     0.293
```

As it looks, the picture is the same with or without side effects.

Changing `other_one()` to `IMMUTABLE` changes the behaviour (maybe surprisingly) to the worse, as it will be called 13 times in both queries.

Comment: Could the decision to call the function again be determined by the presence of a side-effecting instruction in the function's body? Is it possible to find out whether a function with the same parameter(s) is called once or many times per row by looking at the query plan (if, for instance, it had no side-effecting part)?

Comment: @AndriyM I can imagine yes, but currently have no time to play with a debugger to see what is actually called.  Will add a bit about inlined functions (which is not the case the OP should expect, as it sounds).

Comment: @AndriyM, according to: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html a function is assumed to be VOLATILE  if not declared as IMMUTABLE or STABLE. VOLATILE indicates that the function value can change even within a single table scan, so no optimizations can be made.

Answer (score 5):

Try to call it again:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM (
SELECT
     *,
     f(x, y) AS func
FROM table_name
) a
WHERE a.func < 10;
```